# UIWebView Rendering issue in iOS5

Tags: uiwebview, ios5, webkit-transform

I am using a `UIWebView` to render a HTML5 content inside my iPhone app.

The HTML5 involves few Webkit Transform animations.

My issue is, the animation is smooth in iOS 4.x but when I tested the same in iOS 5 (both iPhone & iPad) the animation seems to be slow.

BTW, when I load the same HTML content in Mobile Safari in iOS 5, it seems to work better.

Any thoughts on this? 
Could this be due to the fact that `UIWebView` doesn't have Nitro (JavaScript JIT) support in iOS 5? Is there a property/method in `UIWebView`, which I need to set manually in iOS5 to enhance animation?

Comment: Are you using local HTML pages (form resources) or reaching out to the web. Have you made sure that there are no network issues. Did you try it over wireless?

Comment: @Krishnan: I tested this in both the scenarios, loading HTML from a local webserver (over WiFi) and also tested with having the HTML contents embedded inside the bundle. Both occasions I am getting the same performance.